# Does the viscosity of oil increase with rising temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, viscosity

In order to calculate the viscosity index of a lubricant, apparently you need two input parameters. The kinematic viscosity (mm²/s) at 40°C and at 100°C.

If I got it right, mm²/s means the distance in square millimeters a fluid can travel through a capillary within the timeframe of a second.

Usually, most materials are "more fluid" when heated, which should imply that the viscosity will be lower, the higher the temperature. As far as I know viscosity is the opposite of fluidity => honey is more viscous than water.

So this is my assumption:

- More mm²/s traveled = Lower Viscosity
- Less mm²/s traveled = Higher Viscosity

But now, everywhere I looked online (see e.G. links below), the input value of V40 has to be higher than V100.

Does that mean oil can travel less distances through a capillary when it's hotter?

Please be so kind to explain in layman terms as I'm not too well versed in the field of natural sciences

- https://oil-additives.evonik.com/product/oil-additives/resources/viscosity-index-en.html
- https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_calculate_the_viscosity_index_of_an_unknown_oil
- https://wiki.anton-paar.com/en/astm-d2270-viscosity-index-vi-from-40c-and-100c/

Comment: are you sure it is 40 and 100 degrees, or -40 and -100 degrees, -100 is colder than -40 degrees

Comment: @AdrianHoward I don't think so. According to https://wiki.anton-paar.com/en/viscosity-index/ _[...] Using these parameters and the measured viscosity of the oils at 40 °C and 100 °C, the viscosity index can be calculated_

Comment: Viscosity of liquids decrease with increasing temperature.

Comment: @ChetMiller which is the reason I asked this question. Probably the title is not descriptive enough

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the links, if you input a higher value at the 100°C it says 
"Viscosity 2 has to be lower than Viscosity 1". Note that 100°C is higher than 40°C so in liquids the viscosity should typically be lower. You have a misconception though, higher temperature doesn't always mean lower viscosity. In gases the viscosity normally increases with temperature. Also the behaviour can be a lot more complicated than just 2 values. There is a whole branch of science, Rheology, dedicated to viscosity.

Comment: @SV I understand that viscosity does not correlate to heat linearly, but wouldn't this rule imply, that every oil you can calculate the viscosity index for using this calculator gets more viscous the more you heat it?

Comment: No, the calculator is asking for a **lower** viscosity for the **higher** temperature. It means that when you increase the temperature, the viscosity drops. That is what you expect for liquids.

Comment: @SV so this means that my assumption that higher mm²/s = lower viscosity is wrong. I thought mm²/s means how fast can a fluid travel through a capillary

Comment: Yes, that is the case. A higher numerical value for the viscosity means a higher viscosity. Maybe the problem is in the units, you are calculating the kinematic viscosity but I think the dynamic viscosity is easier to interpret: The units are $Pa\cdot s = N \cdot s /m^2$, it (kind of) gives the opposing force over the area of contact (shear stress).